# How to setup server side pagination with jquery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pagination, datatables

I am trying to setup server side pagination with datatable.

I have used the same following technique in asp.net mvc but somehow its not working with asp.net (webforms).

Following is my .aspx page:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" id="tbl-1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
var oTable = $('#tbl-1').DataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [

                ],

                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": '/mypage.aspx/myMethod',
                    "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'data': function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        return data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    },
                    'async': true
                },
                "scrollY": 300,
                "processing": true,
                "paging": true,
                "deferRender": true,
                "columns": [
               { "data": "Column1" },
               { "data": "Column2" },
               { "data": "Column3" }
                ]

            });

</script>
```

and following is my c# webmothod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=false)] 
public static List<myClass> myMethod(DTVM param)
{
    List<myClass> listmyClass = new List<myClass>();
    return listmyClass;
}
```

but somehow i am getting following error:

```
Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'param'.
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Thanx.

Comment: IN the method you have `DTVM param` as a parameter. You A: never use it and B: do not send it to the webservice. So fix one or the other.

Comment: my understanding is that datatable will automatically send parameters as this code is working in asp.net mvc. . please guide me how to send param to webservice.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=send+parameters+to+webservice

Comment: Thanks for the link but I think "data" part is sending parameters to webservice but somehow i am not able to receive it at service.

Comment: Presumably in your MVC app, `DTVM` is a databound class that handles the parameters that datatables sends in the request. In webforms maybe you have to explicitly get the parameters from the `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: I have checked Request.Form, since its a "POST" request, but I found nothing in there.